# How can I use "this" effectively in this function so it won't affect other click events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I dont understand the what's the problem here. The main purpose of the code is to create dynamic row and remove them. My code works fine. But the main problem here is when I'm using a function to call the redundant code then if i click in one module(page), its affecting the another page. i

dynamicRow.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $schoolAdd = $(document).find('div.schoolAdd');
    var $collegeAdd = $(document).find('div.collegeAdd');

 var $deleteButton='<div><button type="submit" class="reservedFieldRemoveButton"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button></div>';


   $schoolAdd.on('click','button.addButton',function(){
            var $parent= $(this).parent().parent();
            $(this).remove();
            $parent.append($deleteButton);
            $rschoolAdd.append($reservedRowToAppend);
        });
    $collegeAdd.on('click','button.addButton',function(){
            var $parent= $(this).parent().parent();
            $(this).remove();
            $parent.append($deleteButton);
            $collegeAdd.append($reservedRowToAppend);
        });
})
```

this works just fine for school and college module. But the problem is when I'm doing that in a function then

```
  function testFunction(addButton){
       var $parent= $(addButton).parent().parent();
       $(addButton).remove();
       $parent.append($deleteButton);
  }
  $schoolAdd.on('click','button.addButton',function(){
            testFunction('button.addButton');
            $rschoolAdd.append($reservedRowToAppend);
  });
  $collegeAdd.on('click','button.addButton',function(){
            testFunction('button.addButton');
            $collegeAdd.append($reservedRowToAppend);
  });
```

But for using this function when I'm clicking the event of school module, i saw colleage module is also affected. But this should not be happen. They are individual function. I might have used "this" in the wrong way in function I guess. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are accessing to all button elements in all DOM that has class .addButton not only the clicked one. Why haven't you used 'this'?

I've imagined your HTML code because you haven't published (remember to do next time):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $schoolAdd = $(document).find('div.schoolAdd');
    var $collegeAdd = $(document).find('div.collegeAdd');

 var $deleteButton='<div><button type="submit" class="reservedFieldRemoveButton"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>delete</button></div>';
    function testFunction(addButton){
           var $parent= $(addButton).parent().parent();
           $(addButton).remove();
           $parent.append($deleteButton);
      }
      $schoolAdd.on('click','button.addButton',function(){
                testFunction(this);
                $schoolAdd.append("added!");
      });
      $collegeAdd.on('click','button.addButton',function(){
                testFunction(this);
                $collegeAdd.append("added!");
      });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="schoolAdd"><div><button class="addButton">add</button></div></div>
<div class="collegeAdd"><div><button class="addButton">add</button></div></div>
```